Clerk Middeware return 404 error for specific route
I am working on a nextjs 14 clerk project. When I add the
/admin

route to the middlware I get a 404 error. I need to protect this route unless I am an admin. HELP!
import {
  ClerkMiddlewareAuth,
  clerkMiddleware,
  createRouteMatcher
} from '@clerk/nextjs/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const isProtectedRoute = createRouteMatcher([
  '/app(.*)',
  '/api(.*)',
  '/scripts(.*)',
  '/admin(.*)'
]);

console.log;

type UserMetadata = {
  isApprovedUser?: boolean;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
};

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if (isProtectedRoute(req)) {
    auth().protect();

    const { sessionClaims } = auth();

    try {
      const { isAdmin, isApprovedUser } =
        sessionClaims?.metadata as UserMetadata;

      if (isAdmin) {
        //  If the user is an admin, let them proceed to anything
      } else if (!isAdmin && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
        //  If the user is not an admin and they try to access the admin panel, return an error
        return NextResponse.error();
      } else if (!isApprovedUser) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/waitlist', req.url));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in middleware:', error);
      return NextResponse.error();
    }
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)'
  ]
};


I was expecting to be able to access the admin route when logged in as a an admin.

This question is similar to: Clerk 404 when signing out from a protected page (Next.js). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

following the code your not provide you are not handle with else case of
if (isProtectedRoute(req))

so please return it if there a public pages request to middleware like

const intlMiddlewares = createMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales: ['en', 'th'],
  // Used when no locale matches
  defaultLocale: 'en'
});

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if (isProtectedRoute(req)) { // the code logic }
  // else 
  return intlMiddlewares(req); 
}

hope it help !
